# Accessing nameless attributes from JSON in VB .Net using DataContract

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, deserialization, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to serialize in VB .Net a JSON file that contains this:
`"scripts": [[123, 80, [["whenKeyPressed", "space"], ["nextCostume"]]],
                [55, 32, [["whenKeyPressed", "space"], ["doPlaySoundAndWait", "Hello"]]]]`

I'm using `DataContract` and `<DataMember(Name:="scripts")>` and it works fine for the rest of the file, but in this case, the attributes don't have names. `JSONlint.com`, the JSON Validator, is saying this is valid JSON.

How am I suppose the qualify the DataMembers? Also, it has a nameless array in it, how can I can I access it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround by assigning `scripts` to a `List(Of Object)` in the `DataContract`, then casting `scripts` to the desired type at runtime. I casted it as `IList(Of Object)` for the lists and then iterated in them for `For` loops.

It doesn't "feel" as "object-oriented" as the rest and I can't reference the fields by name (since they have none), but it works (with a lot of casting, especially since I work with `Option Strict On`).

If there is a better way, I am open to suggestions.